# Isn't the supposed development in German "schön" > "schon" typologically unlikely

Tags: etymology, linguistic-typology

> **schon** - *yet, already*
>
> **schön** - *well, nice, pretty, beautiful*

Wiktionary has *schon* from an old German word equivalent to modern *schön*. I think this is typologically unlikely, though of course my sample base is too small to be sure. I only see *pretty early*, reflecting the fact that *pretty* didn't always mean what it primarily denotes today.

Specifically, I rather want to compare it to *soon*, which matches idiomatically "ich werde das schon-/-noch machen" (which is difficult to translate, circa *in due time*), though the semantic burden could appear to rest on *noch* "still"<sup>[1]</sup>, depending on which part of the collocation is elided; it's chiefly *schon* in "wir werden das kind schon schaukeln" (we will *well* drive the point home)

<sub>[1]: *noch* is also difficult to translate and etymologically without compare; probably from *h2nek- "to reach, attain", cp. *enough*, *genug*, also *next*, *nachher* "after this'ere"), where DWDS.de sees an influence of *ne, too.</sub>

Perhaps an influence of *schön* could be seen in *schon gemacht* "already did", which carries a connotation of affirmation, cp. *schön gemacht* "well done". *schön* instead appears akin to *show* (think, *nice view*).

Whether *schon* could be a palatilizing dialectal variant of MHG *san, son* (no gloss, but cog. with *soon*, possibly from deictic *so/to-, or perhaps *swe-) and vice versa *schön* related to Fr. *jeune* is not in question, only the typology *schön* > *schon*.

<sub>Note of caution: If it's not likely, that might simply mean that typology is not good meassure in this case, which might mean that the development were overall too complicated to be frequent, to be found out easily.</sub>

Comment: What exactly is your doubt about the proposed origin? Kluge derives it, without any hesitations, from an adverb form of _schön_, and describes it as (initially) modifying words like _bereit_, _fertig_. Not to say that that is the ultimate source of truth, but I see not reason to call it unlikely.

Comment: Maybe you find something useful [here](http://www.arturasratkus.com/sites/default/files/biblioteka/weinacht_1929_zur_geschichte_._schon.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

The adjective schön goes back to Old High German scōni (the umlaut in the first syllable is caused by the /i/ in the second). The adverb schon is from OHG scōno (without umlaut). So it is not really the case that one is derived from the other. Rather they have a common source.

For the semantic compare Pfeifer:

> schon Adv. ‘bereits, früher als angenommen’ geht aus dem umlautlosen
>   Adverb des unter ↗schön (s. d.) behandelten Adjektivs ahd. scōno (9.
>   Jh.), mhd. mnd. schōn(e) hervor (germ. *skaunō). Dessen Bedeutung ‘auf
>   feine, schöne Weise’ geht im 13. Jh. in ‘auf geziemende, gehörige,
>   richtige Weise (an der nichts mangelt)’ und von daher in ‘vollständig,
>   ganz und gar’ über. Verwendungen wie mhd. eʒ ist alleʒ schōne (‘ganz
>   und gar’) bereit können temporal aufgefaßt werden, so daß schōne die
>   Bedeutung ‘bereits’ erhält. Nach dieser semantischen Trennung vom
>   Adjektiv schön entwickelt dieses auch adverbielle Funktion. (Eine
>   ähnliche Entwicklung zeigt sich bei ↗fast und ↗fest, s. d.).

https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/schon

Comment: I wrote: "Whether schon could be a palatilizing dialectal variant of MHG *san, son* ... and vice versa *schön* related to Fr. *jeune* is not in question, ". This should imply likewise that **the derivation from *schön*, or *scon-* as it were, is not in question.** It's relevant perhaps, if the sense from that root is different than I implied, and typologicly likely--which is barely implied in this answer by not expressing any doubt. In my view, Pfeifer could be falling for a true homonym though, or missing an important influence

Comment: The tangent with *fast* "almost, soon" is weak as well. On account of *almost* one might expext a contraction with \*-umo,  \*-umistaz, or simply the superlative suffix, with an unidentified head, inasmuch as the etymology of \*fastuz is insecure, as is that of *fassen* "to grasp". Fastehste? Pfeifer's account is incongruent with *fast* "nahe an" already MHG but the development dated with examples from early New High German ("Frühnhd.", eg. "*weil er fast hundertjerig war*, 16. Jh." ). MHG is compatible with influences from Low German, eg., evidence from OHG missing this sense notwithstanding.